# Can someone explain whats happening here?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have this `FutureBuilder`:

```
  FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : buildPosts();
      },
      future: posts,
  ),
```

I assign the `future:` like this:

```
var posts = PostProvider().fetch();
```

The `buildPosts()` looks like this:

```
buildPosts() {
    List<Post> posts = PostProvider().getPostsOfUser(UserManager.getUser()!);
    
    //do something...
}
```

And the 2 methods (`fetch()` and `getPostsOfUser()`) look like this:

```
List<Post> _posts = [];

Future<void> fetch() async {
    var posts = await PostRequests.fetchPosts();

    _posts = posts;

    print("1" + _posts.toString());
}

List<Post> getPostsOfUser(User user) {
    print("2" + _posts.toString());
    return _posts
        .where((element) => element.usernameOfAuthor == user.name)
        .toList();
}
```

but for what reason the output looks like this:

```
I/flutter (29494): 1[Post{id: 1218ef60-be83-11ec-8f20-0f986fb2b41b, content: wdwdwdawd
I/flutter (29494): , usernameOfAuthor: leguan, time: 2022-04-17 20:46:00.874}]
I/flutter (29494): 2[]
```

From my knowledge the `:` in the `FutureBuilder` will trigger after the fetching has completed so the `_posts` should contain the posts like output 1 but it does not.

Comment: I will encourage you to check others state like `hasData`,  `.hasError`  states. try `snapShot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done` then load list

Comment: Is `PostProvider` a singleton?  If not, you're constructing multiple `PostProvider` instances, in which case the `posts` member of one instance won't be the same as the `posts` member of the other.

Comment: @jamesdlin I feel so embarrassed for not recognizing this mistake. Thank you!